# Windows 10 Updates failing

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

I had information about installing an update from Windows 10 Update assistant. When I had it for the first time, I had my screen enlarged so that the window informing about update was only partially visible. I couldn't see the buttons "Hide" or the progress bar informing about the progress. The window was hiding my whole screen and I couldn't click anything because the buttons were below my screen window. So I pressed Alt+Tab and switched to different window and then closed the window with updates. Then at another time when it showed, I again couldn't see the buttons or anything, so I did the same thing.

After that, I changed my screen resolution or something like that to be able to see the buttons next time. But when the progress bar went to the end, I could see the message "Something went wrong". Here's the screen:

[image: "Something went wrong" screen]

Then, next time, I had the same error at the end. Next time - also the same error. And now from time to time, Windows tries to install the same update, but I get always "Something went wrong" at the end.

My Windows suffers also from the following symptoms:

1. After I log in to Windows, I can see the following message in the corner and I can't see any icons on the desktop (what's interesting, the icons shows up after very long time):

[image: My desktop after running the computer] (Failed to connect to Windows service)

2. Sometimes when I open the file explorator, the files and directories load very slow. There is one directory that never loads and the file explorator always hands on it.

How can I heal my Windows? Do I have to reinstall it?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem.

Comment: can you start the Windows update service? 0x80070426 = ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE

Comment: I used system recovery to recover Windows before doing an update, so my Windows was restored to the previous version, I get a window about an update again, update was installed successfully, then I had to restart my computer. When I was restarting my computer I got a screen saying "Windows is installing updates..., don't turn of your computer". It was updating and it stopped at 38%, it was on 38% for entire night, so I turned the computer of after that. Turned on the computer again, everything was ok, except I got the Update window again and this time the error was  0x80070652 (if I'm correct)

Comment: 0x80070652 = ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_RUNNING, so an installation is already in progress